# Remove attribute in all the elements of the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to remove a attribute in all the elements of the DOM. 
For example:

```
<div id="someId">
   <div ng-model="aaa"></div>
   <p ng-model="bbb"></p>
   <span ng-model="ccc"></span>
</div>
```

I want to remove the **ng-model** attribute from all the elements which are inside the div with id as **someId**. Is there any way to do this using jquery.

Comment: What do you achieve?

Comment: Mixing Angular with jQuery like this is gonna trouble you...

Comment: $('*').removeAttr('ng-model') - for removing the attribute from all elements in DOM

Comment: Removing an AngularJS attribute from an element won't remove the directive or its controller. The element needs to be destroyed and re-compiled with the `$compile` service. There is no simple way to do it with jQuery. Don't even try. Instead read this [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like following using `removeAttr()`.

```
$('#someId [ng-model]').removeAttr('ng-model')
```

Answer (score 0):

use function `removeAttr()`

try this

```
$("#someId").removeAttr("ng-model");
```